# Filter listbox data by using datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to filter listbox data by using datagridview cell instead of using textbox.I am using the following code.

```
     private void searchLedger(string value)
    {
       cn.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from LedgerCreation  Where  ledgerName  like @LedgerName and AddClassification = @AddClassification order by LedgerName", cn);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddClassification", "Cash/Bank");
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LedgerName", "%" + value + "%");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);
        LstReceipt.DataSource = table;
        LstReceipt.DisplayMember = "LedgerName";
        cn.Close();


private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        searchLedger(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString());       
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? What happens? Why not use the EditEdit event instead of ECShowing, which is called before any changes? Depending on the number of records consider using a Bindingsource for filtering to avoid all those trips to the database..!

Comment: EditEdit event, I dont know about this event please give some guidance

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant [cellendedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit?view=netframework-4.8)